# How to use the information in a 4x4 matrix to draw a 2d square in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, 2d, glfw

At the moment I have a function where I pass in a vector2 for position and two int's for the width and height of the image that I want to draw.

It draws a triangle strip and uses the FreeImage library to apply a texture to this square.

However, I have gotten to the point where I want to perform more advanced stuff to these objects, such as setting up Child/Parent relationships, or rotating and scaling the objects.

All of this will become 100x easier if I can figure out how to draw squares with a matrix instead of my current way of doing it.

Comment: How exactly do you get a square from a matrix?

Comment: Where is this matrix coming from?

Comment: I guess I would still have to pass in information for width/height of the quad - but the matrix would hold information about scale/rotation and position.

Comment: Why can't you just take advantage of matrix stacks in OpenGL?

Comment: @Drew McGowen - This is what I am trying to do, I understand how to read a matrix and what all the information in one means, but as of yet I am unable to find a single tutorial that shows me any of the syntax on how to put it into effect.

Comment: You'll want to look at `glPushMatrix` and `glLoadMatrix`

Comment: Do note that the matrix stacks are no longer a part of the OpenGL spec. Most implementations will likely keep it for backwards compatibility, at least in the foreseeable future.